# Microdata nesting

Tags: html, microdata

I currently write the markup for an article page and have a problem with nested microdata. See the markup below:

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    (...)

    <footer>
        <figure itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
            <img itemprop="image">
            <figcaption>
                posted by
                <a itemprop="name">John Doe</a>
                about
                <a itemprop="about">love</a>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </footer>
</article>
```

I want to use the `itemprop="about"` for `itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"`. But the [Google testig tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) says that `itemprop="about"` is not valid for `itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"`.

Is it possible to declare that `itemprop="about"` refers to `itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"` and not to `itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"` without changing the Markup?

Comment: Google testing seems to only select and validate certain microdata tags, while the schema.org website listing shows many tags that I think are all the possible ones. To be honest the whole act of implementing microdata is a tedious pain in the arse and I look forward to the developers of microdata making it easier to implement. I remember having issues with About and instead used "descr", I think. Good luck

Comment: yes it is a pain... 
When i take the prop `about` out of type `Person` it works fine. But this is not possible due to the design of the page. The author and the tag ("love") have to be in the same sentence.

Comment: "without changing the Markup": What *exactly* can’t be changed, and what may be changed? Is adding additional `div`/`span` elements okay? Changing attributes okay?

Comment: yes adding attributes or additional elements is ok, but I can't move `<a itemprop="about">love</a>` out of `<figure>`. Like I said, `<a itemprop="name">John Doe</a> about <a itemprop="about">love</a>` has to be in one sentence.

Comment: I have suggested that this is a duplicate - see above. In your case though, you would need to use a `<span>` element around the `<a itemprop="about">` to have an element to which the hiding itemscope attribute can be applied.